# Deserialize one variable inside an array in JSon. c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I have this json

```
{"841973":[{"name":"Nasus's Agents","tier":"GOLD","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"841973","playerOrTeamName":"GG InstaVayne","division":"I","leaguePoints":0,"wins":515,"losses":524,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":true,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false}]}]}
```

and i just want to get the "tier" data. i know that this variable is inside an array but i cant just get the data out of that array. 
i try doing this.

```
p.summonerRank = (string)JObject.Parse(data2).First.First[p.summonerId]["tier"];
```

data2 is the string i get for the webrequest.
p.summonerId is the number, in this case "841973", but it might change in each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
string  obj = (string)JObject.Parse(DATA).First.First.First["tier"];
```

if you are sure your array will always has one item(or your data is in the first item).

***---EDIT---***

If your requirments are more complex as stated in comments I would recommend a different approach

Declare these classes

```
public class Entry
{
    public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
    public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
    public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    public int losses { get; set; }
    public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
    public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
    public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
    public bool isInactive { get; set; }
}

public class Entries
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tier { get; set; }
    public string queue { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,List<Entries>>>(data);
var division = obj.Values.First()[0].entries[0].division;
```

Now you can access all your propertied in a type safe way (VS's intelisense will help you)

Comment: Im having this excp. 
Additional information: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

Comment: Any idea why this               p.summonerDiv = (string)JObject.Parse(data2).First.First.First.First["division"]; 
 dont give me the "division" var?

Comment: sorry for reviving this, but is there any way i can put "division"/"wins"/"losses" in the entries class and so i get rid of Entry. I try gettint the divison var by this code.                 var division = obj.Values.First()[0].division;
                                                                             var tier = obj.Values.First()[0].tier; The tier one works good but the other just gets a null.